# formatting number in input as user types without ngModel - angular2

Tags: javascript, input, formatting, numbers, angular8

Hello and thanks for help

I have an angular 8 app with reactive form. I want to add thousands separator on input to change the input values from for example:
120 000 to 120,000. I want to do this dynamically, meaning as user type the number the commas are added. Now I have already tried to use rxjs and pipes. Problem is I can't use ngModel  and I don't know how to update my input value once I change it.
Here is the code I have so far...

my template:

```
 <input 
   type="number" 
   matInput id="id" 
   formControlName="value"                                 
   (focusout)="someMethod()"
   [attr.required]="..."
   [readonly]="..."
   [value]="someValue"
   formControl="formattedAmount">
```

can this be done and how? You don't need to give me solution just a hint how to approach this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I have by accident press enter and was on my way to format my question. thank you